# Counting the two value in a attribute using aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some documents in a collection which looks like this

```
{
 "_id" : "5a2e50b32d43ba00010041e5",
 account_id:"23232323"
 status:"accepted",
 keyname:"java"
},
{
 "_id" : "5a2e54332d43ba00010041e5",
 account_id:"2323233"
 status:"pending",
 keyname:"java"
},
{
 "_id" : "5a2e54332d43ba00010041e5",
 account_id:"23232sdsd3"
 status:"pending",
 keyname:"Nodejs"
}
```

I need to get the counts of the pending and accepted status for each keyname for a particular account_id
eg: should give a result like this.

```
   {
    keyname:"java",
    pending:10,
    accepted:10
   }
```

This is the code that I have tried out

```
   db.getCollection("programs").aggregate([
     { "$match": { "account_id": "1" } },
     { "$group": { "_id": "$keyname", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
     { "$match": { "_id": { "$ne": null } } }
   ])
```

which gives a result like this

```
{
    "_id" : "java",
    "count" : 3.0
},
{
    "_id" : "nodejs",
    "count" : 3.0
},
{
    "_id" : "C#",
    "count" : 3.0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "account_id": "1" } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$keyname",
    "accepted": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": ["$status", "accepted"] },
          0,
          1
        ]
      }
    },
    "pending": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": ["$status", "pending"] },
          0,
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```